# Request not being denied with 413 status code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, kestrel-http-server

There is a need to deny requests that have ANY body contents (meaning that `body` size is > 0). I tried using `RequestSizeLimit` attribute but it does not seems to be working properly.

Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [RequestSizeLimit(0)]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {

        return Ok();
    }
```

I am using `Postman` for tests. Provide "qwerty" as a value for body of `POST` request. Here is what `Kestrel` log looks like:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[17]
>         Connection id "0HLN06I1687S4" bad request data: **"Request body too large."**
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException:
>   **Request body too large.    at**
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason
>   reason)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody.ForContentLength.OnReadStarting()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.TryStart()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ConsumeAsync()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication 1
>   application)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication 1
>   application)

Despite this - I still see a 200 (OK) response. I can debug into the method without any issues. It seems like - filter is working fine - but for some reason it it not triggering exceptions. The expected behavior - is "payload too large" (413) status returned for the request and the code execution in method not triggered.

Any ideas or explanation - why I am seeing this behavior?

Comment: Might be stupid of me, but you are returning an OK in your method?

Comment: @AsheraH yes. this in the example. This code should never be executed at all, to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to a question, but a solution to my problem. I have written my own implementation of an action filter that is working as expected.

```
public class PayloadMaximumSizeFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private long _maxContentLength;
    private string _message;

    public PayloadMaximumSizeFilter(long maxContentLength)
    {
        this._maxContentLength = maxContentLength;
    }

    public PayloadMaximumSizeFilter(long maxContentLength, string message)
    {
        this._maxContentLength = maxContentLength;
        this._message = message;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        long? contentLength = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentLength;
        if (contentLength.HasValue && contentLength.Value > _maxContentLength)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult(filterContext.ModelState)
            {
                Value = _message ?? "Request body too large.",
                StatusCode = 413
            };
        }
    }

}
```